# Is there a way to remove the "related pages" block from the Facebook pages?

Tags: facebook-pages

I manage the Facebook page of a company, and at the right appears a "related pages" block added by Facebook which shows a link to the Facebook's page of the competition company. Is there a way to remove this block?

[image]

Comment: Hi Pablo, your question is not clear to me. Can you please attached a screenshot to show what block added by Facebook and you want to remove?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't like it either. You can uncheck it from SETTING. Scroll down to "Suggest similar pages" and uncheck it, then save.
And when you go back to your main page the "related pages" will be gone.